# Background images behind navigation bars and positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, background-position

I'm almost where i want to be with this little experiment. I'm new to css3 and still eagerly learning some things.

I'm trying to get a nav bar to display/show in a div with a background image sitting above it. the key is the bg image has to sit on top of the nav bar like in this image link below.

http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/img/example.jpg

The actual correctly coded functional nav bar is here:

http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/test.html

I'm having trouble getting the full background image to display on top of the nav bar.

The background image has a width of 704px, and a height of 318px. The nav bar has a height of 65px and the same width of 704px. So the complete height size of the div is 383px. I want to stress that I don't want the nav bar to overlay the image, I want it to be the bg image, then the nav bar.

The real non-functional code is as follows:

```css
.mm_pres_main {
  background-image: url(../img/mm_main_tab_d.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div {
  margin: 0%;
  background-position: 0%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  max-width: 704px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.bio_icon,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.stat_icon,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.img_icon,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.vid_icon,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 100px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.bio_icon a,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.stat_icon a,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.img_icon a,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.vid_icon a,
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #004E27;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.bio_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.stat_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.img_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.vid_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
.mm_pres_main #mm_lft_nav_div nav ul li.fut_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!----------------------Head Content Area----------------------------------------------->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test background nav expirement</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum scale=1.0, minimum scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/subnav.css">
</head>
<!----------------------Body Content Area----------------------------------------------->

<body>
  <!----------------------Main Presentation Content Area----------------------------------------------->
  <div class="mm_pres_main">
    <!----------------------Left Sub-Navigational Content Area----------------------------------------------->
    <div id="mm_lft_nav_div">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
          </li>
          <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
          </li>
          <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a padding to the main div the same size as the nav's height. Then set the nav position to absolute and align it to the bottom of the div. Make sure the main div's position is set to relative.

Comment: do you have a working example because i tried it like you said, and it still won't show up/display?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with all of your code and I'll edit that. @AaronWilson